# Is there an R function for retrieving the value of y given the corresponding value of x?

Tags: r, vector

I have a table loaded in r with 2 columns. The first column contains a list of identification numbers and the second column contains the corresponding name of a piece of equipment. Is there an r function that would retrieve the equipment name when I enter the identification number?

For example, if my table looks like this...

```
ID #        Equipment name
1           Car
2           Bike
3           Plane
```

...I want to enter "1" and get the string "Car".

Comment: You can try `df[df$ID == 1, ][2]`.

Comment: (Or, if you want to return a vector, `df[df$ID == 1, 2]`)

Answer (score 0):

Here you go!

```
# create data
df = data.frame(id = c(1,2,3,4), equipment = c("car","bus", "bike", "train"))

# convert factors to characters
df$equipment = as.character(df$equipment)

# subset data
# option 1
subset(df, id == 1)$equipment

# option 2
df[df$id ==1,]$equipment
```

Comment: Thank you! With this I ran into the same problem as with the suggestion from slava-kohut. It seems that no matter the input, I'm getting a list of all levels from the equipment column.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
df <- data.frame(id = c(1,2,3,4), equipment = c("car","bus", "bike", "train"),
stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

find_eq_name <- function(df, id){
  df[df$id %in% id, ]$equipment
}

find_eq_name(df, 1)
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried this and when I run find_eq_name I get this response: factor(0) 5095 Levels:

Comment: @TylerJimenez you can convert factors to characters in your data frame if I understood you correctly